# jQuery-Only slider not sliding

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Basic jQuery-only slider that is supposed to fade between slides on arrow click.

Can't seem to figure out why this one won't work, as I've made similar ones before using a similar method without plugins.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b988tfna/1/.

I've also got the code for a testimonials slider below the main slider in JSFiddle, where I'm having problems aligning the buttons/dots for this slider and also sizing them properly. The height and width are set the same, but they're taller than they are wide, and margin-left/right:auto isn't centrally aligning them.

Would rather not combine these issues into one post but I've been trying to solve them for hours now without any solution.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="sliderArrow">

    <a href="#" id="prevArrow"><img src="img/prevArrow.png" style="height:85%; width:85%"></a>

</div>

<div id="slider">

    <div class="slide activeSlide">

        <div class="slideContent">

            <h1>Creating Digital Success Stories.</h1>

            <h4>Intro | Innovation | Results</h4>

            <p>Mauris sed ipsum nisi, Aliquam eget sagittis erat. Nam ut auctor erat. Maecenas sollicitudin dignissim urna, eu elementum ante varius at. Mauris porttitorultrices mauris, eget pretium lorem blandit in. Nulla sollicitudin viverra ante sed venenatis.</p>

            <a href="#contactUs" id="enquireButton" class="button" alt="Enquire Now Button" style="position:absolute; margin-top:20px">Enquire Now</a>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slide">

        <div class="slideContent">

            <h1>Slide 2.</h1>

            <h4>Intro | Innovation | Results</h4>

            <p style="font-family:'Effra-Light'">Mauris sed ipsum nisi, Aliquam eget sagittis erat. Nam ut auctor erat. Maecenas sollicitudin dignissim urna, eu elementum ante varius at. Mauris porttitorultrices mauris, eget pretium lorem blandit in. Nulla sollicitudin viverra ante sed venenatis.</p>

            <a href="#contactUs" id="enquireButton" class="button" alt="Enquire Now Button" style="position:absolute; margin-top:20px">Enquire Now</a>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slide">

        <div class="slideContent">

            <h1>Slide 3.</h1>

            <h4>Intro | Innovation | Results</h4>

            <p style="font-family:'Effra-Light'">Mauris sed ipsum nisi, Aliquam eget sagittis erat. Nam ut auctor erat. Maecenas sollicitudin dignissim urna, eu elementum ante varius at. Mauris porttitorultrices mauris, eget pretium lorem blandit in. Nulla sollicitudin viverra ante sed venenatis.</p>

            <a href="#contactUs" class="button" alt="Enquire Now Button" style="position:absolute; margin-top:20px">Enquire Now</a>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slide">

        <div class="slideContent">

            <h1>Slide 4.</h1>

            <h4>Intro | Innovation | Results</h4>

            <p style="font-family:'Effra-Light'">Mauris sed ipsum nisi, Aliquam eget sagittis erat. Nam ut auctor erat. Maecenas sollicitudin dignissim urna, eu elementum ante varius at. Mauris porttitorultrices mauris, eget pretium lorem blandit in. Nulla sollicitudin viverra ante sed venenatis.</p>

            <a href="#contactUs" id="enquireButton" class="button" alt="Enquire Now Button" style="position:absolute; margin-top:20px">Enquire Now</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="sliderArrow">

    <a href="#" id="nextArrow"><img src="img/nextArrow.png" style="height:85%; width:85%"></a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
color:#fff;
z-index:2;
padding:100px 0;
}

.slide
{
display:none;
width:100%;
}

.activeSlide
{
display:block;
}

.sliderArrow
{
position:relative;
height:auto;
top:50%;
margin:-200px 10% 0 10%;
z-index:99;
}

.slideContent
{
width:65%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nextArrow').click(function() {

        var currentSlide = $('.activeSlide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        if (nextSlide.length == 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first(); 
        };

        currentSlide.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('activeSlide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(1000).addClass('activeSlide');

    });

    $('#prevArrow').click(function() {

        var currentSlide = $('.activeSlide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

        if (prevSlide.length == 0) {
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last(); 
        };

        currentSlide.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('activeSlide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(1000).addClass('activeSlide');

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.container {
      max-width: 400px;
      background-color: black;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .container div {
      background-color: white;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      display: none;
    }
    .container img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    button {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .next {
      right: 5px;
    }

    .prev {
      left: 5px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="demo">
      <button class="next">Next</button>
      <button class="prev">Previous</button>
      <div class="container">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
        </div>
        <div>
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/any"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/nature"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/architecture"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/animals"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/people"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/200/tech"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="explanation">
      Building a slideshow like pattern that can accurately cycle through a number of unknown divs, forwards and backwards. Trying to use as little code as possible. Leave a comment if you see a way to do it better!
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
var currentIndex = 0,
  items = $('.container div'),
  itemAmt = items.length;

function cycleItems() {
  var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
  item.css('display','inline-block');
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex += 1;
  if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
  cycleItems();
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  clearInterval(autoSlide);
  currentIndex -= 1;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
  }
  cycleItems();
});
```

**Please try this link:-https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/**

Ok.  May be you can try this link:-http://visuallightbox.com/content/30-best-image-sliders-173.html